# Does Docusign Basic API support Oauth JWT grant?

Tags: docusignapi

I have built an integration with the Docusign API, but am unable to successfully complete the JWT auth flow with our production account.

Everything works fine in our sandbox account - I went through all the steps described in the docs (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken),
and successfully promoted the integration key to our production account.

However, with the production account, running through the same code to initiate the JWT results in a 400 Bad Request error, with no additional information about the nature of the failure. I've double checked that we are using the correct oauth base domain (what Docusign calls `aud`) and that RSA keys and redirect URLs are correctly
configured for the production account.

I've also gone through all of the "go live" steps, except for one which mentions migrating users, since it doesn't seem
like this functionality is available on our production account dashboard. On the sandbox account, which has all enterprise features enabled,
the sidebar has a section for "Users and Groups" but there is no such section on our production account.

I'm wondering if the root of the problem is that our production account, which is the Basic API level account, doesn't have adequate permissions
to support the use case I'm building for.

Unfortunately I can't get a straight answer from either account reps or tech support folks as to whether this is true.

Comment: Are you using the API directly or the SDK? The SDK needs to be explicitly set to use the production authentication server.

Comment: Thanks Larry - yes we are explicitly configuring the SDK to use the production auth server.

Comment: Please contact go-live@docusign.com if you're still having a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to use the same RSA key you used in Sandbox in Production by any chance?
Also, did you actually get your IK certified and active in production?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Inbar - I am not using the same RSA key in production, I generated new RSA key pair for the production account, and am using it. And yes, I did get the IK reviewed, and it passed review and appears to be correctly associated with our production account.